# Stock Exchange in US

Tags: united-states, stock-exchanges

I am currently searching the trading calendar of stock exchanges in the US. But different countries have different practiceS in trading.
For example, in Australia, ASX is for listing and trading; while CXA is only for trading (not allowed to list companies).
I searched from internet; there are three main stock exchange at US which are NYSE, AMEX and Nasdaq.

I have few question about US stock exchanges:

1. Do three stock exchanges have same trading calendar and same settlement schedule?
2. Can stock list at one exchange, for example AMEX, but trade at both AMEX and NYSE?
3. Is there other listing exchange at US?
4. Is there other exchange only for trade but not listing at US (like CXA at Au)?

Comment: I can't tell if your criteria would include the Chicago Mercantile Exchange (CME) or Chicago Board of Trade (CBOT).  These handle mainly options and derivatives-but they are world leaders in their categories.

Comment: Thank for your reply. I am only focus on stock trading. Other instrument like future, option, swap are excluded. So please tell me more.

Comment: Relevant: [Can US stocks list on one stock exchange but trade on other US stock exchanges?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/128269)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest route for you to go down will be to consult wikipedia, which will provide a comprehensive list of all US stock exchanges (there are plenty more than the ones you list!). Then visit the websites for those that are of interest to you, where you will find a list of holiday dates along with the trading schedule for specific products and the settlement dates where relevant.

In answer to the other part of your question, yes, a stock can trade on multiple exchanges. Typically (unless you instruct otherwise), your broker will route your order to the exchange where it can be matched at the most favorable price to you at that time.